# How to read Google+ profile and email scope data with GoogleTokenResponse in Java?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

My goal is to read the user's Google profile and email data (plain Gmail accounts, not a Google+ account, if the user does not have one) on my server with OAuth2.

I have used the following guidelines:

- [Google+ Sign-In for server-side apps](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow)
- [Migrating to Google+ Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration)
- [Quick-start sample app for Java](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/java)

Finally, I now have a `GoogleTokenResponse` Java object on my server that I could use to read the profile and email data from the Google server... if I only knew how.

What is the cleanest way of doing this in Java with the Google Java API(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was pretty obvious in the end, but it took me a while to bridge the gap between sorting out the OAuth2 stuff to get the `tokenResponse` as in the sample app, and then actually reading data from a Google API.

In my case, the key was to find the Javadoc for Google+ API in [Google APIs Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/). Then the rest was easy:

```
GoogleCredential cred = new GoogleCredential().setFromTokenResponse(tokenResponse);

Plus plus = new Plus.Builder(TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, cred)
    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();

Person person = plus.people().get("me").execute();          
List<Emails> emails = person.getEmails();

String name = person.getDisplayName();
String emailAddr = emails.get(0).getValue();
```